# How to make distributed Angular deployment aware of versions

Tags: angular, git, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I have my Angular app deployed in multiple environments like dev, qa, staging, production. Once the app deployed through Jenkins pipelines, I want to make my app tell me which version exactly they were built from.

To verify whether this is the correct build I wanted to deploy with properties like build-time, last commit information (branch, user, message) 
Is there a way to do this with out digging the build files?

Thanks in advance